# JS IntersectionObserver and ClassList.remove()/add()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the navbar's background to regular or light depending on which section is currently being displayed. However, for some reason, the code is adding the 'nav-light' class in the sections I told it to remove, and removing in the sections I told it to add.

Codepen with the basic code [here](https://codepen.io/fcherini/pen/qBjqVKg). But I couldn't add the scroll-snap effect there, so it's not 100% true to what's happening.

[Live version](https://fcherini.github.io/whynotwork/) so you can see exactly what happens.

The nav changes to match the background rather than to contrast it, and the last section "contact" does nothing.

This is the entire code that I have:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navbar = document.querySelector("nav");

const options = {
  threshold: 0.9,
};

// window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
//   navbar.classList.remove("nav-light");
// });

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function (entry) {
    let classList = entry.target.classList;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (classList.contains("contato") || classList.contains("projetos")) {
        navbar.classList.add("nav-light");
      } else if (
        classList.contains("header") ||
        classList.contains("habilidades") ||
        classList.contains("formacao")
      ) {
        navbar.classList.remove("nav-light");
      }
    }
  }, options);
});

sections.forEach(function (section) {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The codepen is different than your example code, so I will give my answer based off the codepen:

Change the `threshold` to `0` instead of `0.2`, because it is adding the class too early (unless that is your desired result).

But to fix the initial issue, you simple need to swap `add` and `remove` and it will work.

However, there is an inherent flaw with your intersection observer, because you are observing sections in relation to the viewport.  So even with the "fixed" version you will still see odd behavior on scroll up, because the new section is coming into the viewport before the `nav` has reached the new section, making it seem like the `nav` is changing colors incorrectly.  You will need to have a different approach to achieve the desired result.